# How to Calculate the Possibility of a Straight

Tags: texas-hold-em, odds

I am trying to work out how to calculate the possibility of a straight occurring during the flop.

I have some basic understanding from websites and online videos, but I’m unable to work out some of the following scenarios:

[image]

How am I able to calculate this?

Comment: You haven't asked a specific question. What do you want the probability of? Making a straight by the river? That requires drawing an event tree for each line of your question, and properly summing the branches. It's something you learn in first year statistics, and would take a full page to outline here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question has some problems.

It appears you are looking for chance of making a straight on the turn (not flop).  There 47 cards out not 46.

If you need two cards you cannot make a straight on the turn.

For the river on 567 you could use 8/47 * 8/46 = 2.96% = 1/33.78.  This is not exact as you could hit 3 or 9 on the first card and only have 4 outs on the river but then you also have 16 outs for the first.

Comment: @user6336941 If it is correct you can give it a check.